# How to restrict the apps in the share dialog in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I can share some text or files with external apps with [Xamarin.Essentials: Share Feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=android).

Well, can I restrict the apps shown in the popup to share? For example, can I set it to show gmail but not whatsapp in the popup?
I need this for both ios and android in the Xamarin.Forms app. How to handle it?

Thanks.

Comment: No.  The OS/user determines what apps are available to share based on content type.  Your app doesn’t get to overrule the users preferences

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Please feel free to post if you have the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.Essentials: Share Feature only provide the the method to share the file or text for other applications. The system will detect the file type (MIME) and request a share. Each platform may only support specific file extensions.

Here is the [Share Class API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.share?view=xamarin-essentials), you can refer to this.